# How do you list tracked files (git ls-files) in magit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

How do you list tracked files (git ls-files) in magit?

Comment: There exists (in Magit 2.11.0, at least) a function called `magit-insert-tracked-files`, which can be run using `j t`... However, that doesn't (at least for me) seem to actually create the section, despite that the code seems to indicate that it would.  It instead gives the error `Section "Tracked files" wasn’t found`... I'm not sure why, or how to fix it, so leaving this as just a comment.  Presumably, though, this (or something related to it) would be the way to do this...

Answer (score 6):

@tarsius is right about the fact that there is currently no built-in command for doing this.

You can, however, do this:

<kbd>:</kbd> `ls-files` <kbd>RET</kbd>

`:` is bound to `magit-git-command` which allows you to

> Execute a Git subcommand asynchronously, displaying the output.
>   With a prefix argument run Git in the root of the current
>   repository. [...]

---

You can of course automate the process described above by recording a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) or defining a custom command and binding it to a key sequence of your choice:

```lisp
(defun magit-ls-files ()
  "List tracked files of current repository."
  (interactive)
  (if (derived-mode-p 'magit-mode)
      (magit-git-command "ls-files" default-directory)
    (message "Not in a Magit buffer.")))

(define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "K") 'magit-ls-files)
```

Comment: Mode map needs to be modified as a hook `(add-hook 'magit-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "K") 'magit-ls-files)))` so that magit-mode-map is defined prior to use

Comment: @eludom Using `lambda` to add functionality to hooks has a couple of disadvantages. It makes values of hook variables hard to read, and you can't easily remove functionality via `remove-hook`. So if you want to use a hook you should wrap the body of your `lambda` in a `defun` and add that to the hook instead. Another solution would be to simply `(require 'magit)` before modifying the mode map **or** use `eval-after-load` to wrap the code in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on [the comment from @lindes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993868/how-do-you-list-tracked-files-git-ls-files-in-magit#comment84998648_24993868), you can configure Magit to include a list of tracked files in the status buffer by doing

```
(magit-add-section-hook
   'magit-status-sections-hook
   'magit-insert-tracked-files
   nil
   'append)
```

for example in your `.emacs` file.  (See the [Status Sections](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Status-Sections.html) and [Section Hooks](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Section-Hooks.html) docs for details on what this does.)

Then, in the Magit status buffer, typing the `j t` key sequence @lindes mentions will go to the tracked files section.

Answer (score 2):

Magit doesn't do that but [dired-k](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-dired-k) shows the (git) status of each file, which might be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not as clean, but what I have always does is <kbd>l f TAB</kbd> from the `magit-status` buffer. That is...

1. <kbd>l</kbd>: lower-case "L" for `Logging`, which calls `magit-key-mode-popup-logging`
2. <kbd>f</kbd>: "f" for `File log`, which calls `magit-file-log`
3. <kbd>TAB</kbd>: which calls `minibuffer-complete`

You could make this a little easier with a custom keybinding and/or macro.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet works great for me.  To use it, run `M-x my-git-dired` and enter a git work directory (or a subdirectory).  The resulting buffer is a normal dired buffer, so it's possible to, for example, query-replace on multiple files.

```
(defun my-git-dired (dir)
  (interactive
   "DDirectory inside a git repository: \n")
  (condition-case nil
      (dired (cons "*git-dired*" (my-git-ls-files dir)))
    (error (message "Execution of git-ls-files failed"))))

(defun my-git-ls-files (dir)
  (save-excursion
    (cd dir)
    (split-string
     ;; The following is shell-command-to-string with error handling added.
     (with-output-to-string
       (with-current-buffer
           standard-output
         (unless (= 0 (call-process shell-file-name nil t nil
                                    shell-command-switch "git ls-files"))
           (error "Not a git repo")))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use `M-& git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -- ls -ld` followed by `M-x dired-virtual RET`.  The latter requires [the `dired-x` library to be loaded](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredExtra#Dired_X).